# Climbing Gym Management

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, best-practice

I would like to know if CiviCRM is the right choice to manage contacts and entrances of a climbing Gym.
At present we manage subscrition manually with forms, and sell single entrance tickets and multiple prepaid entrance cards.
I would like to store the contacts subscribed with expiry date, track every entrance and manage the balance of the 12 entrance pre paid card.
Is this possible using native CiviCRM or extensions ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

civicrm doesn't have an out-of-the-box solution for the 'tracking every entrance and manage the balance of the 12 entrance pre paid card', but that said, there are ways you can work through this I expect. I know we did a solution once upon a time for a Museum which also offered a 'subscription' which we implemented as a 'membership'.

The difficulty as I see it with the 12 entry card, is that you don't have a timeframe - hence membership isn't appropriate - nor is it an Event.

You could make a special Contribution type that has a custom field with checkbox for 1 through 12, and have that come up on the system so you can add an extra tick on it, or use Activities and somehow track the count on them (perhaps even like a Case).

Maybe someone else can suggest an Extension that I am not aware of.